# Nginx proxy one port to multiple ports

Tags: nginx, proxy, port

I have only one port opened in firewall and multiple services running. I want to redirect a request based on URI to different application. For example if I am accessing http:example.com:8443/test1 to be redirected to one application running on port 8440 and if am accessing http:example.com:8443/test1 to be redirected to the master nginx process running on port 80

My configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:8443;
    location  /test1{
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8230;
    }
}
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:8443;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    location  /test2{
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80; #Nginx master webserver port
    }
}
```

But when I am accessing localhost:8443/test2 I am receiving a `403 Forbidden` but if I am the redirect port for test1 to 80 like this

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:8443;
    location  /test1{
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80;
    }
}
```

it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You should only have 1 server since they are both listening on `127.0.0.1:8443`. You would then have two location blocks inside that server, for example:

```
server {
    listen      127.0.0.1:8443;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location  /test1 {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8230;
    }


    location  /test2 {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80; #Nginx master webserver port
    }
}
```

Also, just be aware that you're *proxying* the traffic, rather than redirecting it.  You will probably need a lot more configuration depending on how your applications are set up, since the `/test2` will most likely be passed directly into your server on port 80 too.

**Update:** for PHP support, you'll need to make sure that php-fpm is installed, and will need a location block in your master nginx server, similar to:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://your_ip_address:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was generated by the fact that I am trying to configure nginx master web server as a file server and I have created a php page which was added as argument to the upload_pass  directive `upload_pass /example.php;` and the nginx server doesn't know how to handle php. Maybe I need to import a new module in nginx.

Comment: There's a helpful guide here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-16-04-server, I've also updated my answer with a quick example.